# laravel 5.2 deployment with Heroku

Tags: laravel, deployment, laravel-5, heroku-postgres

I have a website build in Laravel 5.2 that is working fine locally on my machine using XAMPP. I have deployed the project online using Heroku and PostGres add-on. I am able to register a user, login and input information to one of my tables in my database. I am unable to input information into at least two of my tables.

Error in my laravel.log file:

> local.ERROR: ErrorException: Undefined variable: user in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/dsd-cms/storage/framework/views/.

In my terminal when I enter :

> var_dump(getenv('DATABASE_URL'));

I get:

> syntax error near unexpected token `getenv'

My website works on my local host using XAMPP, but not when using Heroku & PostGres. Any ideas?

Comment: try `php artisan view:clear`.

Comment: I am still receiving the same syntax error, but my data is being stored to the database correctly. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

update `storage` folder permission.

Comment: Why should one do that? Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it